# Wordpress theme customization issue with services setup under Business Page

Tags: wordpress

I am setting up a wordpress page using spacious theme. I have got 5 services which need to be placed in one single row, but the theme allows only 3 services to be one row and other two get on new line. As div and featured images are added using services widget, I assume no changes can be made in markup file too.

Comment: Can you provide me your page link and theme which you use?

Comment: As mentioned in the question..I am using spacious theme...

Comment: I suppose this theme is using a 12 column grid, so... you'll have to edit your theme to achieve a [5 columns layout](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=5+columns+layout).

Comment: This services could have image as well as some description so it will be good to show 3 in a row and add another two  in bottom row , it will look more elegant and easy to read. Currently theme will be using 4 column for each service, in bottom row use 6 column for each service. @Pranjal

Comment: pass your website link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be having theme options for services data...

You'll need to do some serious php coding to add fields and get them working ( may need editing the theme )...

Instead of using themes you can use any of the page builders which will solve your problem easily and you will be able to add as many rows/columns as you want without having to edit the theme.

Some nice page builders  include [Tailor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tailor), [Pootle Pagebuilder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pootle-page-builder/) and [Beaver Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/beaver-builder/).

Read about page builders here... http://pippinsplugins.com/wordpress-page-builder-plugins-critical-review/

Comment: Hi Pranjal, Just to let you know I have developed Pootle Pagebuilder... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a child theme and add the following codes to style.css of child theme.
[Here](http://themegrill.com/blog/tutorial-creating-wordpress-child-theme/) is the link to how to create child theme.

```
.tg-one-third {
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    margin: 0.5%;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px;
}

.tg-after-three-blocks-clearfix {
    clear: none;
}
```

If you have problem in creating a child theme I made one [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BydwvoE1zMiibkVyanE2NnlHMG8/view?usp=sharing). Just upload and activate the spacious child theme.